# Vertical alignement messed up due to the image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1 <img src="image.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
</ul>
```

Vertical alignment of this menu is messed up due to the addition of a small image inside on of the li's. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/7n4sZ/

Is there any fix that'd work cross-browser?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve made you a jquery solution. Directly with css is dificult if you add some images with different height. With more math, and grouping by height, it is possible.

But to your problem - [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ8Mb/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
img {vertical-align:bottom;}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/anupamsm/7n4sZ/1/)

Comment: Hmm..it still looks the same, maybe the text moved slightly up but still not aligned.

Comment: that depends on your image size.Try top and middle also,whatever suits you the best.I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anupamsm/7n4sZ/6/) by the way

Comment: Or you can put image inside a separate `<li></li>` tags after the first one